# Search from current position in file or website

Tags: macos, search

It seems the default search (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>) in Mac applications like Preview and Safari searches from the very top of the page.

Is there any way to make it so that searches start from the current position or page in a website or PDF?

On longer webpages and PDFs this behavior is very annoying as I have to scroll back down to where I was reading.

Answer (score 0):

Many applications have their own specific implementation of find, so there isn't a universal answer, but try selecting some text first (or just clicking on some text, as if there is a cursor even if there isn't one visible).

This seems to work in Safari, but not in Preview.